# SELECT LIMIT 1 per column value?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Lets say I have the following table

| user_id | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | thats cool |
| 2 | awesome |
| 3 | i hate this |
| 3 | okay |
| 6 | this is weird |
| 6 | hello? |
| 6 | what is it |
| 9 | how are you |
| 16 | too slow |
| 16 | yes |
| 17 | alrighty |

How can you select one row per `user_id`? So my results would be:

| user_id | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | thats cool |
| 3 | i hate this |
| 6 | this is weird |
| 9 | how are you |
| 16 | too slow |
| 17 | alrighty |

Is this possible with a single efficient query? Or are sub-selected necessary?  Is it possible to somehow use `DISTINCT` on a single column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what `GROUP BY` is used for. Get one row (per group). In this case, it will show all distinct `user_id` values and for the rest of the columns, you can (have to) use aggregate functions like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, `SUM()` as you will have more than one values per group and only one can be shown.

```
SELECT
    user_id
  , MIN(comment) AS comment  -- it will show the first in alphabetical order  
                             -- you could also use MAX()
FROM
    tableX
GROUP BY
    user_id ;
```

MySQL allows also the following unorthodox solution, that will return one (more or less random) comment per user:

```
SELECT
    user_id
  , comment
FROM
    tableX
GROUP BY
    user_id ;
```

This last query will not work but raise an error if the (stricter) `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode is enabled. In the recently released 5.7 version, this mode is the default and a new function, `ANY_VALUE()`, is provided. For more details, see the [MySQL Handling of `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) page. The query can be written now:

```
SELECT
    user_id
  , ANY_VALUE(comment) AS comment
FROM
    tableX
GROUP BY
    user_id ;
```

Note that with either the "unorthodox" version or using the recent `ANY_VALUE()` function, if we add more columns in the `SELECT` list, their values is not guaranteed to be from the same row, just from a row in the same group. The way they are selected is not exactly random, depends on the execution plan and the indexes used.

Comment: Are there any other ways to specify which row gets pulled for a user_id? Any way to specify an ORDER BY kind of?

Comment: Besides `MIN` and `MAX` ?

Comment: yes, pretend like perhaps there were other columns in the table and I wanted to grab the comment from the user that was first alphabetically and posted the nearest the NOW(). So sort of like ORDER BY multiple columns, but obviously using ORDER BY in this query would simply reorder the results, not actually manipulate which rows are SELECTED.

Comment: Then it's more complex. See this other question: [MySQL Query - How to get most recent demographics?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23238/mysql-query-how-to-get-most-recent-demographics/23272#23272)

Comment: You'll also find a ton of similar problems in SO site, under the **[`[greatest-n-per-group]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+greatest-n-per-group?sort=votes&pagesize=50)** tag.

Comment: Will all values from the fields that aren't grouped on be from the same row, or will fields be pulled randomly from the rows within the group?

Comment: @T.BrianJones do you mean in the "unorthodox" query, if you add all other columns in the SELECT list? It's the first, they may not be from the same row. It's not exactly random but the values can be from different rows (from the same group).

Answer (score 0):

I have a cheap-and-nasty solution for this. Put query that creates the original data in a CTE and add a `RANK()` column which you partition by user_id, and order by comment

Then select from the CTE `where rank = 1`

Comment: You can put the full query in your answer. There is nothing cheap or nasty about it in my opinion. It just wasn't available in MySQL (neither CTEs not window functions) when this question was asked, 10 years ago.