# select n values per group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Lets say I have the following table

```
-----------------------------
| user_id   | comment       |
-----------------------------
| 2         | thats cool    |
| 2         | awesome       |
| 3         | i hate this   |
| 3         | okay          |
| 6         | this is weird |
| 6         | hello?        |
| 6         | what is it    |
| 9         | how are you   |
| 16        | too slow      |
| 16        | yes           |
| 17        | alrighty      |
-----------------------------
```

How can you select two rows per user_id? So my results would be:

```
-----------------------------
| user_id   | comment       |
-----------------------------
| 2         | awsome        |
| 2         | thats cool    |
| 3         | i hate this   |
| 3         | okey          |
| 6         | this is weird |
| 6         | hello?        |
| 9         | how are you   |
| 16        | too slow      |
| 16        | yes           |
| 17        | alrighty      |
-----------------------------
```

Is this possible with a single efficient query? Or are sub-selected necessary?

Comment: Originally incorrectly posted as an "answer" to [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/24908/1192), Prateek's question is looking for a modification that will provide two rows per group. Edited question accordingly.

Comment: Thank's @Paul, makes more sense now. I'll remove my assumption from my answer since it is no longer necessary.

Comment: Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` in the question. Does the table not have any unique key?

Comment: Also: you want 2 rows per user_id but which 2 rows? How are the 2 to be selected? (for `user_id=6` for example there are 3 rows, why `'this is weird'` and `'hello?'` were selected and not `'what is it'` ?)

Comment: Related tips: [groupwise-max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the technique described in:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/

to mimic:

```
row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)
```

In your case that would be something like:

```
SELECT user_id, comment, row_number 
FROM (
    SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @user_id=user_id
                             THEN @row_number+1                                
                             ELSE 1                          
                        END AS row_number
         , @user_id:=user_id AS user_id
        , comment     
    FROM t        
       , (SELECT @row_number:=0,@user_id:='') AS u     
    ORDER BY user_id, comment 
) as v 
WHERE row_number <= 2;
```

Comment: Is this a documented, guaranteed technique in MySQL?

Comment: I don't think so, all and all user variables appears to be a hack that more or less happens to work. The docs at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html mentions that `the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.` In practice it appears to be working, but I would not bet my life on it.

Comment: Exactly, in MariaDB, the differences in the optimizer may result in not the wanted outcome. It has to do with the `ORDER BY` being optimized out of the query.)

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible to trick the optimizer by adding `LIMIT <large number>` in the inner select. In theory the ORDER BY can be optimized out anyway if it is guaranteed that the limit is larger than the size of the sub-select, but I doubt that any optimizer would do that.